# What's the use of the following c.Args() > 0

Tags: go

This code is from the `cli` Go package: https://github.com/codegangsta/cli

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "greet"
    app.Usage = "fight the loneliness!"
    app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name:  "lang, l",
            Value: "english",
            Usage: "language for the greeting",
        },
    }

    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) {
        name := "someone"
        if len(c.Args()) > 0 {
            name = c.Args()[0]
        }
        if c.String("lang") == "spanish" {
            println("Hola", name)
        } else {
            println("Hello", name)
        }
    }

    app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

I'm a Go beginner and I understand everything, except this part:

```
if len(c.Args()) > 0 {
    name = c.Args()[0]
}
```

What does that block says? Why is it necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `Args` returns an object `Args` which is a slice of strings (see [`context.go`](https://github.com/codegangsta/cli/blob/master/context.go)):

> ```
> type Args []string
> ```

To get the first element of that slice (`[0]`) one has to check beforehand if it's not empty, thus the `len` test. If you don't do this and the slice happens to be empty, you get an `index out of range` runtime error and your program panics.